# Disable JSP compilation

Tags: google-app-engine

Sometimes I want to disable the JSP compilation when I am doing the 'appcfg.cmd update war'. 
What arguments can be given for appcfg.cmd?

-Aswath

Answer (score 0):

Based on reviewing the doc's and code I do not see a way.